# Swagger Docs not generating for Spring Boot app

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am pretty new to spring boot but for some reason my swagger ui is not allowing me to accees the API.  I tried to follow a couple tutorials but no luck on being able to see the API's.   Below is the screenshot that I get when loading (I tried a couple other URLs as well) and some relevant code.

[image]

Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.starter.controllers"})
public class StarterRestStarterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StarterRestStarterApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("A simple starter service")
            .description("A simple calculator REST service made with Spring Boot in Java")
            .contact(new Contact("my info", "http://myurl.com", "myemail@gmail.com"))
            .version("1.0")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Greeting Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new GreetingService().greet(name);
    }
}
```

Gradle.build

```js
buildscript {
 ext {
  springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
 }
 repositories {
  mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
 }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.starter'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}


ext {
 springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.SR4'
}

dependencies {
 compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix')
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
 compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0'
 compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0"
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
 imports {
  mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
 }
}
```

Comment: can u give a try by replacing @RequestMapping("api/v1") as @RequestMapping(value="api/v1") and @RequestMapping("/greeting") as @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")

Comment: Try adding @EnableSwagger2 to your config class.

Comment: Thank you @Justas you were 100% correct.   I accidentally forgot to include that.   

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@EnableSwagger2` to your config class.